# How do I reset a string array variable

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with 4 different arrays.

All are set up like this

```
shared stringvar array arr1 := split({client_relations.sales_value}, "&");
'';
```

I need them to reset for each group. How do I do that? I tried something like this

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared stringvar array arr1 := " ";
```

But I got an error saying the formula could not create an array.

Answer (score 2):

Someone suggested to me I try:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared stringvar array arr1 := "";
'';
```

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

Create a new formula putting the below code in, calling it reset or something along those lines and place it in the group header.

```
StringVar Array arr1;
Redim arr1[0];
```

However, you will have to put any outputs in the group footer for this to work as it resets all data at the start of a new group.

Comment: I was trying the redim but for whatever reason it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible `Redim arr1[0];`, because of error "dimensions must be between 1 and 1000". I try to assign a dummy blank array to reset `arr1` as follows:

```
StringVar Array arr1;
Local StringVar Array dummy;
arr1 := dummy;
```